# Как выводить View с самого верха экрана?

Tags: java, android, view

Смартфон имеет вверху врезку с камерой. При выводе на экран View андроид начинает выводить изображение от нижней точки врезки (справа и слева от врезки серый пустой фон). Как заставить программу выводить View от самого верха экрана, не обращая внимания на врезку камеры? Я нашёл в документации, что можно этим управлять с помощью атрибута (layoutInDisplayCutoutMode) моего View. Но я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в андроид и не смог понять как использовать этот атрибут в моём коде.  Подскажите, как в коде программы указать, что View должен выводиться на экран от самого верха экрана?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190381/fullscreen-app-with-displaycutout

Comment: @Arty Morris, вариант который там описан у меня не работает